# Isomorphism between two manifolds definition.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I want to try and show that a map between two manifold product spaces is an isomorphism. Im just a bit confused as to what 'isomorphism' means in this sense. At first I thought it was equivalent to the map being a homeomorphism but then I read some things saying it required the map to be linear and so on.

Any chance someone would be able to explicitly define what an isomorphism between two manifolds means?

Comment: If two manifolds are both smooth, we can say that they are isomorphic if there is a smooth diffeomorphism between them. But I think you should add some context, as (1) it is not a very common usual in differential geometry (we simply say that they are diffeomorphic), (2) don't quite see how that linear thing comes in.

Answer (score 1):

In the class of *differentiable* manifolds an isomorphism is a diffeomorphism, that is to say an homeo $f$ such that both $f$ and its inverse are differentiable.

In general, when we speak about *isomorphism* it is understood the class of *morphisms* we are working with (for example continuous maps, differentiable maps, linear maps, holomorphic maps, polynomial maps et cetera...).

For example, for complex manifolds, isomorphisms are biholomorphisms; for algebraic manifolds isomorphisms are biregular maps; for PL-manifolds isomorphism are PL-homeos et cetera.

Thus, if the manifolds you are dealing with have linear structure, you may want to require isomorphisms to be *linear*. But it depends on the context.

Comment: So assuming you wanted an isomorphism between say just two maniflds (not necessarily smooth), this would be equivalent to a bijection between the two manifolds?

Comment: @A.P. corrected, thanks.

Comment: @Scott Nope, a bijection is an isomorphism of sets. A bijective function $f$ between two manifolds is an isomorphism if both $f$ and its inverse preserve the topological structure of the manifolds, i.e. if $f$ and its inverse are continuous.